# What's wrong with this encryption code?

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, public-key-encryption

I have the following code that generates an AES-128 one-time key. After that I encrypt this one-time key using an RSA public key read from a certificate. The encrypted bytes is always 0. Why?

```
    // Generate a one-time key
    KeyGenerator keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");
    keyGenerator.init(128);
    SecretKey oneTimeKey = keyGenerator.generateKey();
    System.out.println("Encrypted bytes length: " + oneTimeKey.getEncoded().length); // prints "Plain bytes length: 16"

    // Retrieve public key from certificate
    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("D:\\test.cer");
    CertificateFactory factory = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    X509Certificate certificate = (X509Certificate) factory.generateCertificate(fileInputStream);
    PublicKey publicKey = certificate.getPublicKey();

    // Encrypt one-time key using the public key.
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);
    ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayOutputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    CipherOutputStream cipherOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(byteArrayOutputStream, cipher);
    cipherOutputStream.write(oneTimeKey.getEncoded(), 0, oneTimeKey.getEncoded().length);

    // Retrieve the encrypted bytes.
    System.out.println("Encrypted bytes length: " + byteArrayOutputStream.toByteArray().length); // prints "Encrypted bytes length: 0"
    cipherOutputStream.close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to flush your cipher output stream before getting a byte array.

Comment: Thanks! I called cipherOutputStream.close() before getting the byte array, and it works now. The strange thing is that this code has been working fine for weeks without flushing the ciper output stream.

Comment: Then you shouldn't accept my previous answer :) It was wrong, because I confused "key size" and "block size" terms. Still, it seems the solution is to call flush method :)